# I can not place colorbar properly with Facegrid using seaborn in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

I am try in to graph a four dimensional data with seaborn using Facegrid feature. I am not able to place colorbar at the right place. I would like to have one colorbar and my Facegrid is 2 by 3. 
Trying different similar reiteration

[This is what is get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEGlB.png). Proper Facetgrid, Facetgrid with bar but second column squeezed, no data in Facetgrid, two empty subplots with plt.subplots option.

My code gives my all kind of issues.
Here is an example of code

```
#
# I have variable X1, Y1,  Pa and ROI. 

df=pd.read_csv (‘data’)


# plot all measure on x-y facet, with hue=Pa
# very energy consuming to plot with all data !!!

# fig , axes = plt.subplots(1,2, squeeze = False)
sns.set()
g=sns.FacetGrid (df, col = 'ROI', hue = 'Pa', col_wrap = 2 ) 

#map plots on grid
g= g.map (sns.scatterplot, 'Y1', 'X1', )

#add axis for color bar
# having issues of using adjust

# plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1, top=0.9, left=0.1, right=0.8, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.1)
# cb_ax = g.add_axes([0.83, 0.1, 0.02, 0.8])

#createing color bar as legend for Pa
color_array=pd.DataFrame (df.Pa)
color_array ['a']='1'
color_array.a=pd.to_numeric (color_array.a, errors = 'coerce')
color_array.Pa=pd.to_numeric (color_array.Pa, errors = 'coerce')
color_array=np.array (color_array)
plt.imshow (color_array)
plt.colorbar ()

plt.show ()
#having issues with saving at some reiterations
plt.savefig ('plot', dpi = 400)
```

Comment: Hi spylaw01, please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before you write your next question! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Comment: Thank you. I will do better next time.